# Comparing proofs of Chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, chain-rule

Rudin in PMA, gives proof of chain rule as this:

> **Theorem:** Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f'(x)$ exists at some point $x\in [a,b]$, $g$ is defined on an interval $I$ which contains the range of $f$, and $g$ is differentiable at the point $f(x)$. If $$\begin{align}
>    h(t)=g(f(t))   &&(a\le t\le b),\end {align}$$ then $h$ is differentiable at $x$, and $h'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x)$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $y=f(x)$. By the definition of derivative, we have $$f(t)-f(x)=(t-x)[f'(x)+u(t)],\tag4$$$$g(s)-g(y)=(s-y)[g'(y)+v(s)],\tag5$$ where $t\in [a,b], s\in I$, and $u(t)\to0$ as $t\to x$, $v(s)\to0$ as $s\to y$. Let $s=f(t)$. Using first (5) and then (4), we obtain $$\begin{align}h(t)-h(x)&=g(f(t))-g(f(x))\\&=[f(t)-f(x)]\cdot[g'(y)+v(s)]\\&=(t-x)\cdot[f'(x)+u(t)]\cdot[g'(y)+v(s)],\end{align}$$ or if $t\ne x,$ $$\dfrac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}=[g'(y)+v(s)]\cdot[f'(x)+u(t)].\tag 6$$ Letting $t\to x$, we see that $s\to y$, by the continuity of $f$, so that the right side of $(6)$ tends to $g'(y)f'(x)$.

But, [these](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_notes.pdf) errata, on page 5, under heading P.105, say that "Rudin’s proof skirts the point that makes proving the Chain Rule difficult: that $f(t)$ may take on the
value $f(x)$ infinitely often in the neighborhood of $x$".  My question is, does this issue remain even after errors as mentioned in link are taken care of?

Also, does [Apostol's proof of chain rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1udm.png) take care of possibility of infinitely many $f(t)=f(x)$ in neighborhood of $x$?

Comment: It would seem simpler to me to treat $f'(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) \neq 0$ separately.

Comment: I just saw a proof just now that makes this distinction, and can get rid of '$f$ continuous', @copper.hat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue in the proof.
Once $x$ and $y$ are fixed, the functions $u$ and $v$ exist uniquely and are continuous with zero values at $x$ and $y$.
Perhaps in some other proofs obtaining the same value infinitely often is an issue, but no in this one.

Apostol's proof is fine as well.
The proofs are valid even if $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Also, why do we need to assume $f$ continuous on whole $[a,b]$ In Rudin theorem? I have a link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222685/theorem-5-5-in-baby-rudin-do-we-need-the-continuity-of-f-on-the-entire-interv), but comment and answer there seem to differ there!

Comment: @Silent It was assumed for convenience, so as not to make the statement and proof too convoluted. It is actually enough that $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: So, where is it used in Rudin's proof?

Comment: @Silent You have $s=f(t)$, and you can't expect $s\to y$ as $t\to x$ without continuity. (This is where he says "by the continuity of $f$".) The proof is not optimal; less assumptions would do, but continuity on the whole interval makes life (=mathematics) simple.

Comment: I also wonder, if I need to invoke linked errata in proof? Or that's unnecessary?

Comment: @Silent The erratum doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped a lot.

Comment: @Silent I'm glad to be able to help!

Comment: Don't we already know that $f$ is continuous at $x$ since it's differentiable there? Do we need continuity on a neighborhood as well?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Continuity at the point should be enough, unless I miss something subtle. Mere differentiability should suffice for the reason you state. I didn't want to go into optimizing the proof in terms of assumptions.